# Pop Up form before Executing PHP Function

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, popup

What I Want to achieve :

1. A user enters my page called (Certificate Search)
2. HTML Form asking for fname, lastname , and serial number.
3. when user Clicks 'Submit' , Form method 'GET' will send data to a PHP Query to my database to display Data based on the details in the form.
4. I want it so that each time a user click 'Submit' There would be a pop up form . (Preferably with input fields like name , company name , email address , so on, and this form would send all this data AND the data from the HTML form before this to my E-Mail address . The User HAS to complete this form before proceeding to view the results. )

Any Help Please? or someone willing to point me to the right direction?

My HTML Page At the moment :

```
<? PHP CODE to receive fname,lname and serial from HTML form ?>
<h2>Search for certificate holder details through our databases below :</h2>
&nbsp;

Please enter exact :

<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" />
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" />

Exact 8-DIGIT Serial Number:<input type="text" name="serial" />
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Search" />

</form>&nbsp;
```

Comment: You could use a multi-page form (javascript) or store the data in a session and redirect to the other form. If that is submitted too, you load the previous form data from session and use it to build your query.

Comment: Get a Look on Ajax request and response, It will send the data to the the server without any change in the page